# TimePicker ValueChanged Event

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

I previously used the DateTimeUpDown and have now switched to using the TimePicker which better suites my needs. There is however on problem. The DateTimeUpDown had an event ValueChanged which is missing from the TimePicker.

This is mostly because the TimePicker does not inherit from UpDownBase. Is is possible to add this event so that we can perform other work as soon as the value in the TimePicker changes?

Comment: Did you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.timechanged.aspx ???

Comment: Also if required, Check http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/datepicker-and-timepicker-controls-with-windows-8-1-store-apps/

Comment: I want code example in C#. Which could should I use to change the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen above as a solution for my problem.

```
<xctk:TimePicker Name="tpFrom"  Format="LongTime"  TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TimePicker_TextChanged"  TimeInterval="00:15:00.000" Value="{Binding Path=StartTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></xctk:TimePicker>
```

In the code behind in our eventhandler we'll put the focus on our timepicker.

```
private void TimePicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tpFrom.Focus();            
}
```

Comment: But in this code, it shows error for TimePicker name as "name does not exist in the current context".